# React-native: Can't build the android app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am a newbie, just started dipping my toe in react-native. The first hello world app did run okay, as I started the second one I am getting this error:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:java.lang.RuntimeException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.034 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your app is now multidex, you can learn mor about [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

To solve this, just enable multidexing on `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```